# Logging wordpress errors on AWS AMI server

Tags: linux, wordpress, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

so I have a basic out of the box wordpress installation setup on my instance of a ec2 AMI server. I want to set up wordpress logging. I checked that logging is set to true in my wp-config.php file, and I am expecting a standard debug.log file to show up in wp-content. However this is not happening. Are the errors being piped somewhere else? Could it be that that I am missing some small configuration detail (that usually is the case.) I'm not sure what is wrong. Thank you for your time and help.

Edit: so now I can see that the PHP error log is in the logs folder, accessible from the root directory by default. However, what is still confusing is that I want to be able to route my wordpress errors to the logs that exist, or perhaps just set up my own debug.log file in the existing log directory. I'm reviewing wordpress logging and PHP ini stuff, but I cannot generate a log file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any additional information that you could share on the AMI? How did Wordpress get installed and how would I reproduce to try to see the same issue? I'm guessing it is something about the OS install in the image or an interaction with something in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin in all Wordpress developments. You simply create a file called php-error.log in the root of your Wordpress install, set a few lines in wp-config (instructions after activating plugin in dashboard), and your log will also automatically appear in the dashboard.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-monitor/